# Pandas DataFrame: Calculate metrics between specific index elements/positions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of length `N` and certain indices/positions `ni` in arbitrary distances. Now I want to calculate metrics between two consecutive index elements `ni` and `ni+1`.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['id'] = ['W', 'W', 'W', 'Z', 'Z', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z']

print(df)

          A         B         C         D id
0  0.347501 -1.152416  1.441144 -0.144545  w
1  0.775828 -1.176764  0.203049 -0.305332  w
2  1.036246 -0.467927  0.088138 -0.438207  w
3 -0.737092 -0.231706  0.268403  0.464026  x
4 -1.857346 -1.420284 -0.515517 -0.231774  x
5 -0.970731  0.217890  0.193814 -0.078838  y
6 -0.318314 -0.244348  0.162103  1.204386  y
7  0.340199  1.074977  1.201068 -0.431473  y
8  0.202050  0.790434  0.643458 -0.068620  z
9 -0.882865  0.687325 -0.008771 -0.066912  z
```

Now let's say I have `n1=0`, `n2=4`, `n3=5`, `n4=9` and want to calculate the arithmentic mean between these for columns A and B e.g. mean(`n1`,`n2`), mean(`n2`,`n3`), mean(`n3`,`n4`),  mean(`n4`,`n5`).

The expected output would be a DataFrame with 4 rows (means) and two colums (A and B).

Any hints are welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats the expected output look like?

Comment: I have adapted my answer!

Comment: Ohk whats `n5` now

Comment: @Bharath `pd.cut`, it is you show time

Comment: @Wen cant tell if I can use `pd.cut` here. Maybe concat with list comprehension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for pd.concat wiht list comphrehension i.e

```
l = [n1,n2,n3,n4]
newl = list(zip(l,l[1:]))
# [(0, 4), (4, 5), (5, 9)]
pd.concat([df.loc[i[0]:i[1],['A','B']].mean() for i in newl])
```

Output :

```
A   -0.044437
B    0.295627
A   -0.884344
B   -0.005827
A    0.451703
B    0.077761
dtype: float64
```

In your case to get the expected output we can concat vertically and transpose the dataframe

```
ndf = pd.concat([df.loc[i[0]:i[1],['A','B']].mean() for i in newl],1).T
```

```
          A         B
0 -0.044437  0.295627
1 -0.884344 -0.005827
2  0.451703  0.077761
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution is really short, generic and solves it for any length of passed indices! Also thanks for all the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to slice:

```
In [11]: n1=0; n2=4; n3=5; n4=9

In [12]: df.loc[n1:n2, "A"]
Out[12]:
0    0.347501
1    0.775828
2    1.036246
3   -0.737092
4   -1.857346
Name: A, dtype: float64

In [13]: df.loc[n3:n4, "B"]
Out[13]:
5    0.217890
6   -0.244348
7    1.074977
8    0.790434
9    0.687325
Name: B, dtype: float64

In [14]: df.loc[n1:n2, "A"].mean()
Out[14]: -0.086972599999999956

In [15]: df.loc[n3:n4, "B"].mean()
Out[15]: 0.50525560000000003
```

Comment: I dont think  `+1` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. But if my index vector has 10.000 elements (n1...n1000), isn't it possible to pass it somehow in one operation e.g. groupby or something similar?

Comment: @Bharath it is if you want to include the n2th/n4th row in your calculation.

Comment: @CordKaldemeyer is `n` a numpy array, how are you getting n1, n2, n3, ... n1000 ?!

Comment: @AndyHayden I think +1 is necessary for `iloc` not `loc` maybe. Because selecting `5` for `n2 =4` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use .iloc

```
n1=0
n2=4
n3=5
n4=9

df
Out[22]: 
          A         B         C         D id
0 -0.238283  0.109911  0.351710  0.048457  W
1 -0.325829  0.017999 -0.965771 -0.860846  W
2 -1.095183 -0.448895  1.690735  0.140668  W
3 -0.016087  1.025236  1.634730  0.755837  Z
4 -1.394894  0.343395 -0.522272  0.308791  Z
5  0.308004 -2.243848  0.359605 -0.806157  Y
6 -0.149900  0.305214 -2.250844  0.385339  Y
7 -0.562943 -0.651464  1.241993 -0.963086  Y
8 -0.465702  1.429940 -0.146888  0.436931  Z
9 -0.766442  0.899470  0.210917 -0.751582  Z

df.iloc[n1:n2]
Out[23]: 
          A         B         C         D id
0 -0.238283  0.109911  0.351710  0.048457  W
1 -0.325829  0.017999 -0.965771 -0.860846  W
2 -1.095183 -0.448895  1.690735  0.140668  W
3 -0.016087  1.025236  1.634730  0.755837  Z


#The Mean for each Column within your index range  
df.iloc[n1:n2].mean()
Out[24]: 
A   -0.418846
B    0.176063
C    0.677851
D    0.021029
dtype: float64

#The Mean for each Row within your index range
df.iloc[n1:n2].mean(axis=1)
Out[25]: 
0    0.067949
1   -0.533612
2    0.071831
3    0.849929
dtype: float64

#To get the mean for a specific Column
df["A"].iloc[n1:n2].mean()
Out[31]: -0.4188455553382261
```

I hope the above answers your question.

Comment: Mean of only ['A','B'] and I dont think its a different one than what @Andy posted. Its better to use loc than iloc

Comment: @Bharath Thanks for the comment. Can you please clarify why loc is better than iloc? I m new to pandas.